# stacked bar plot for sales plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot for the total sales of each item in each category using R, my dataframe looks like:

| category | item | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accessories | Backpack | 59507 |
| Accessories | Handbag | 61047 |
| Clothing | Blouse | 71029 |
| Footwear | Boots | 62363 |

This is the code I have:

```r
ggplot(sales_amount, aes(fill = item, y = amount, x = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.6) +
  labs(title = "Sales Total for Each Item Within Each Category", x = "Category", y = "Sales Total")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  coord_flip()
```

and I got the bar plot looks like this:

[image]

The total amount is correct, however, the proportional of the subcategory is wrong. I figured its because it shows the number of times each item appears in the table. How to change my code to make the bar plot showing the sales amount of each items? looks like this?(chatgpt generated it)

[image]

Comment: Welocome to SO. It'd be easier to hrlp you if you provide a reproducible example with your questions. Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) to know how.

Answer (score 0):

I created a synthetic dataframe trying to reproduce yours. I don't know what was wrong with your code but this seems to work:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sales_amount <- tibble(
  category = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
  item = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = TRUE),
  amount = runif(100, 1000, 10000)
) |> 
  distinct(category, item, .keep_all = TRUE)

sales_amount |>
  ggplot(aes(fill = item, y = amount, x = category)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.6) +
  labs(title = "Sales Total for Each Item Within Each Category", x = "Category", y = "Sales Total")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-21 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>